# Looking for spanish music video

Tags: music-video, pop

I am looking for a spanish music video which I found in 2015/2016. It was about a couple living together in an apartment and it was sang by female artist. There was a scene where she was playing a piano, and the guy came back from the outside (playing football) and  he made a mess with his dirty shoes. 
It was pop music, I found it by looking similar artists to some pop singers like Miranda Cosgrove or maybe Taylor Swift on last.fm.

If you have any idea what was it or who sang that please let me know!
FYI - It was rather less familiar artist as far as I remember.

Thanks in advance!